# Set Options Menu Visibility always On. (Android, Xamarin, MVVMCross)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I was wondering if there is a way to keep the Android options Menu programmatically permanently visible.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. Is there any additional detail you could provide? Perhaps a screenshot of the effect or some code? When is an options menu not visible? Please update question with more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I try to understand your question, it is a strange thing to do. If you want a menu to be visible all the time, then it has nothing to do with the options menu. Just create a (sub)view/layout with the menuitems you want to use.

Also remember the options menu can work differently between Android versions, and even certain  device vendors do funny things with the options menu, that could influence the way your app behaves.

Comment: Thanks guys thats what I did eventually.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to do with MVVMCross.

You need to do this in the Android project code, using the Android API for the menu.